# Подключение к базе данных

Tags: node.js, mongodb, база-данных

Проведите, пожалуйста, ликбез. Что такое по сути соединение с базой данных? Как лучше организовать работу с бд - открыть одно соединение и только его и использовать или делать по принципу открыл-закрыл?
Использую nodejs, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше использовать коннекшн пулы, независимо от типа базы.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool

Comment: Тут написано, что пул это кэш соединений с базой. Вот у меня никак не получается понять что такое 'соединение с базой'. Это же не функция и не объект, которые можно добавить в массив.

Comment: Connection это объект, который можно добавить в массив :)

Comment: Но лучше, конечно, не в массив, а использовать готовую библиотеку для connection pool-ing-а дя того языка и базы, которую вы используете.

Comment: Вот тут прям описано что делать конкретно в вашем случае. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656574/how-to-manage-mongodb-connections-in-a-nodejs-webapp " reuse the db object that results from MongoClient.connect(). This gives you pooling"

Comment: Спасибо, помогли